# PHP go to another page and getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, redirect

I have 2 pages

1. HTML page with a form
2. PHP action page for the form

Based on this, if everything is successful with the form submission, I want to go back to the first page and open up a modal using `document.getElementById`.

I know to do this, I would need the header("Location: blabla") function in my PHP page to go back to the first page, but how am I supposed to open up the modal after getting to that page?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Seems like you'd be better off using AJAX. Submitting a form to a different page and then going back to the form page doesn't make much sense. Keep the user on the same page if that's what you need.

Comment: If you can't do Ajax, use $_SESSION to store a value in a hidden input on your form page. Then test if your value is present with JS and do the actions you need accordingly.

Comment: [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns the DOM element specified by its `id`. It doesn't open a 'modal' (which doesn't exist as a native web UI component). Please share some code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use ajax in this case, yet if you have to do it this way you can use the query prams, for example you redirect the user to your html page like this

```
header("Location: blabla.html?m=some message to show")
```

then in your html page, you need to check if this param exists then display the modal like this

```
searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if (searchParams.has('m')) { // searchParams.get('m') then open the modal or do what ever you want. }
```

edit: you can use any other param instead of the message, it could be what modal to show, or whatever